# Get all Pdf file Urls with Nutch2

Tags: mongodb, apache, web-crawler, nutch

I am using Nutch 2.3.1 with MongoDB for persistence. My goal is to extract the file URLs without downloading them.

Right now it is downloading the file. How could I disable the download and persist the URL only in the database?

How could I extract all crawled URLs from Nutch2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want to accomplish, this may require some modifications:

If you don't want to parse/extract text from the PDF files, then you could set a value low for the `http.content.limit` which will basically prevent Nutch from downloading more that the bytes that you specify there, but still will be able to discover the URLs of the files, and will download a fragment (the number of bytes that you specify).

Of course this will also affect the rest of the URLs that you want to fetch/download.

One way to go could be to write your own protocol plugin that will prevent you from downloading any PDF file.